# is that possible using VS2010 to read .vspx file(or other profiling related files) generated by VS2012

Tags: c#, profiling

question as above described and I couldnt install VS2012 Express to read the report since I have Windows 7.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh266747.aspx) MSDN document you can't:

> Profiler report files:
>    You can open Profiler report files (.vsp .vsps,
>   .psess, and .vspf) in both Visual Studio 2012 and Visual Studio 2010
>   SP1. **You can’t open a .vspx file in Visual Studio 2010 SP1**.